# Dividing a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

Given: $$\sin {x} ⋅ \cos {3x} = \sin {x} ⋅ 2\sin {3x} ⋅ \cos {3x}$$

Can I divide by $\sin {x} ⋅ \cos {3x}$ ?

If I check $\sin {x} ⋅ \cos {3x} = 0$ I get 2 more answers that are correct to the original equation. What is the meaning of that? Do I add those answers at the end? Or do something else?

Comment: As answered by 5xum, factor first is the best way to stay strict.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you then add the answers at the end. This is because your equation is really

$$\sin x\cdot \cos 3x(1-2\sin 3x) = 0$$

and you probably know that $a\cdot b=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$.

---

Whenever you have an equation of the type

$$f(x)\cdot g(x)=f(x)\cdot h(x)$$

you can divide the equation by $f(x)$, of course, but it is also clear that **if** $f(x_0)=0$, then $x_0$ is obviously the solution to the equation, since $$f(x_0)\cdot g(x_0) = 0\cdot g(x_0) = 0 = 0\cdot h(x_0) = f(x_0)\cdot h(x_0).$$